# Are these RewriteBase and RewriteRule useful for my SEO?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have used a developing subdirectory to install a wordpress platform. When I have asked to programmers to move everything to the root they have used rewriting urls rules in the htaccess file in this way:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L] 
    </IfModule>
```

The rules are working but I would like to know if this is a good way for SEO. Does the search engine see these rules in a transparent way or could I be banned? Could I use these rules for a permanent time or should I use some other rules?

Answer (score 0):

> The rules are working but I would like to know if this is a good way for SEO.

The rules themselves don't improve SEO for you, it's more important to setup your wordpress links correctly. I'm pretty sure that out of the box, wordpress permalinks are setup just fine for SEO. Make sure they're turned on and setup the way you want. You'll have to [take a look at the wordpress documentation for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

> Does the search engine see these rules in a transparent way or could I be banned?

These rules work transparently from the client. Thus search engine bots will request a wordpress permalink and not see any `/test/index.php` stuff at all. You won't get banned.

> Could I use these rules for a permanent time or should I use some other rules?

These look like default wordpress generated rules, there's no reason to change them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. You have answered about the trasparency of these rules for the bots. In this way I have understood that bots will see and will put in their index www.domain.com/ and not www.domain.com/test/index.php

Comment: thanks for your reply. You have answered about the trasparency of these rules for the bots. In this way I have understood that bots will see the url as stated in that rule and will put in their index as www.domain.com/ and not www.domain.com/test/index.php. These are not rules completely made by wordrpress but there are also inserted "RewriteBase /test/" and "RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]". These are the rules I have asked about.